# How to properly cleanup/close database after test class

Tags: spring, postgresql, integration-testing, spring-test

I've problem with spring boot integration test. I have aproximately 300 tests and during their execution more than 150 postgres connections are opened. 
Tests are annotated almost everywhere by SpringRunner. Sometimes there is more annotations.

This also causes that the test are executing without the end probably.

In my opinion database is not removed with context change but have no idea how could I invoke this process.

[image]
[image]

Comment: When the context closes (at least it should) the datasource will be closed and as such the enclosing connections. If that doesn't happen Spring isn't managing the pool.

Comment: @M.Deinum any solution?

Comment: properly manage the pool... So find the source of the leaks.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you explain me how? or simply send any article. I'm using JpaRepository only without any magic.

Comment: I would start checking your tests... Especially where you are using `@MockBean` and or `@TestPropertySource` etc. those will start a new spring context and thus datasource. The default is to cache 32 spring application contexts. Als the fact that you only use `JpaRepository` doesn't mean you are properly configuring the datasource.

Comment: @M.Deinum So I'm not using any of this annotation and my configuration is:

`datasource:
        password: 
        url: jdbc:postgresql://
        username: 
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create
        properties:
            hibernate:
                format_sql: false
                c3p0:
                  min_size: 3
                  max_size: 10
                  timeout: 1800
                  max_statements: 0`